# Pop Up for Setting directory path

Tags: files-and-directories

I am trying to build certain modules in Mathematica 9. I want it to dynamically ask for the directory path ( like file explorer ) when the code cell is executed.

How can I do that ?

```
(*================================================= DIRECTORY CONTROL \============================================*)

Directory[];
(*current directory*)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];(*set to local roaming directory *)

SetDirectory["File_Directory"];
(* set to local roaming SubDirectory *)
```

Comment: @rm-rf -rf Thank you. How can I enable the pop up by default. Shift+Enter should display the folder Browser window. Is there a method to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To choose the directory interactively, use `SystemDialogInput`, which brings up a native dialog

```
SystemDialogInput["Directory"]
```

[image]

If successful, it'll return the chosen directory as a string, or return `$Canceled` if you select "Cancel".

Comment: Exactly what I want.

Comment: Any way to add custom message like : choose the sub folder or choose the subsubfolder ... It may create confusion when more than one such dialog pop up right ...

Comment: It would be bad UX to have multiple popups appearing at the same time for such a simple (and common) operation. Instead, if you're using something like a `Button[]` for your interface, consider a descriptive name for the  button, such as `Button["Choose directory", dir = SystemDialogInput["Directory"]]`

Comment: Ok sounds good. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Extending R.M's answer:

```
Button["Choose directory", dir = SystemDialogInput["Directory"], Method -> "Queued"]
```

works without error.